# How can I show my text above my hover effect in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a hover effect, but the text isn't showing above the :before class.

Here is a codepen of the project https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/WNrJdbR

I'm not sure what edit's I would need to make to show the text above since the button text I can't add a z-index

Here is the css

```
.btn-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none; 
  color: black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #FF0072;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-2:hover {
  color: #000;  
} 

.btn-2:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: #FF0072;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn-2:hover:before {
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

Here is the html

```
 <button class="btn-2">HOVER</button>
```

Comment: I cant open your codepan project

Comment: what you mean you can't open the codepen? the link is working fine on both my browsers

Comment: I opened it was my internet sorry bro

Comment: what happen if you use buttons background not before you need to add z-index

Comment: you can edit the code directly in codepen, so you can see exactly if something works or not

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this css code:

```
.btn-2 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn-2:hover:before {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: does nothing still

Comment: Hey, sorry, I forgot to add minus to the hover style, I updated the answer, please try again.

Comment: You can accept my answer if you think that it solved your problem.

Comment: Better than my solution, just two extra lines

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<button class="btn-2"><span>HOVER</span></button>
```

css

```
        .btn-2 {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            border: none;
          color: black;
            border-radius: 4px;
            transition: 0.3s ease all;
            font-size: 2rem;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            border: 3px solid #FF0072;
            border-radius: 4px;
            position: relative;

          }

          .btn-2:hover {
            color: #000;  
          } 

        .btn-2:before {
            transition: 0.5s all ease;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 50%;
            right: 50%;
            bottom: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            content: "";
            background-color: #FF0072;
            z-index: 1;
          }

          .btn-2:hover:before {
            transition: 0.5s all ease;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            opacity: 1;

          }

.btn-2 span { 
  color: orange;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-2:hover span {
  color: #000;
}
```

eg: [image]

ref: https://codepen.io/nani554/pen/jOWxYmG